# Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable'

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-phone-8.1, jurassic

I'm getting this error when I try to use `Jurassic.ScriptEngine` in my WinPhone 8.1 Project.

The entire error message:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: is this even possible?